# Play 2.0.3 still getting Futures timed out after [5000] after setting promise.akka.actor.typed.timeout

Tags: playframework, akka

I am stilling getting this error even I set the following timeout value to 10s. The system is Play 2.0.3.

```
2012-08-14T08:52:20+00:00 app[web.1]: play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [5000] milliseconds]]
2012-08-14T08:52:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:134) [play_2.9.1-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
2012-08-14T08:52:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:115) [play_2.9.1-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
2012-08-14T08:52:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:318) [akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
2012-08-14T08:52:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:113) [play_2.9.1-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
2012-08-14T08:52:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:626) [akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
2012-08-14T08:52:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:197) [akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
2012-08-14T08:52:20+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [5000] milliseconds
2012-08-14T08:52:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   at akka.dispatch.DefaultPromise.ready(Future.scala:870) ~[akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
2012-08-14T08:52:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   at akka.dispatch.DefaultPromise.result(Future.scala:874) ~[akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
2012-08-14T08:52:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   at akka.dispatch.Await$.result(Future.scala:74) ~[akka-actor-2.0.2.jar:2.0.2]
2012-08-14T08:52:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaPromise.await(Akka.scala:43) ~[play_2.9.1-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
2012-08-14T08:52:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise$class.await(Promise.scala:55) ~[play_2.9.1-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]
2012-08-14T08:52:20+00:00 app[web.1]:   at play.api.libs.concurrent.AkkaPromise.await(Akka.scala:28) ~[play_2.9.1-2.0.3.jar:2.0.3]



$ tail -1 conf/application.conf 
promise.akka.actor.typed.timeout=10s
```

Comment: I'm getting the same behaviour in Play 2.1, but only sometimes. I'm not able to pinpoint what exactly causes this. I hardly use jobs or Akka directly, I only have one Akka scheduler called from `onstart`: `Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(10 seconds, 10 seconds, monitorActor, Tick)`. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: you can try play.akka.actor.typed.timeout=12s

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
play.akka.actor.typed.timeout=10s
```

Comment: I tried it, but still getting Futures timed out after [5000] milliseconds.

Comment: Btw, I added this config to additionalConfiguration and used it in test case like this: play.api.test.FakeApplication(
                path,
                classloader,
                Scala.toSeq(additionalPlugins),
                Scala.toSeq(withoutPlugins),
                Scala.asScala(additionalConfiguration)
                );

Comment: What do you mean by `additionalConfiguration`?  This should go in your `conf/application.conf` file.  You might also want to try and set `play.akka.actor.retrieveBodyParserTimeout=10s`

Comment: I mean I put this config to a test case's FakeApplication. However, that test case still fails with [5000] timeout.

Comment: so far I'm still not able to verify if 'play.akka.actor.typed.timeout' is working. I will comment here again if I see it works.